# mySQL freezing when doing a table replace with python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm executing a long python function that reads the data from 2 mySQL tables, appends it, transforms it, and writes the outputs back to sql. For some reason, the first write, which is 'append' works fine, the other one, which is 'replace' freezes (i.e. script is running, can't execute sql commands through terminal but nothing happens). The write is very small, when I disconnect (restart mySQL service) and do the write as a separate line of code, there's no problem and it takes less than a second. Here's the code I'm using:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

def local_connect(login_local,password_local,database_local):
    engine_input="mysql://"+login_local+":"+password_local+"@localhost/"+database_local
    engine = create_engine(engine_input)
    con = engine.connect()
    return con

con=local_connect(login_local,password_local,database_local)

...

aaa.to_sql(name='aaa',con=con_,if_exists='append',index=True)
bbb.to_sql(name='bbb',con=con_,if_exists='replace',index=True)
```

aaa and bbb are pandas dataframes.

EDIT solved it by reconnecting after the first 'to sql'

```
con_.close()
con_=connect.local_connect(login_local,password_local,database_local)
```

What is the reason and a better way to do this?

Comment: Typically, using `if_exists='replace'` results in a `DROP TABLE` being run, which requires an exclusive lock on the table. Are you unable to run commands agains *any* table, or just `bbb` ?

Comment: My python script is stuck running, and when I concurrently open cmd and open mysql that way, anny commands I type in are not being executed (i.e. stuck as if executing but nothing happens). So I can't run any commands at all.

Comment: Does using a context manager `with local_connect(...) as con:`, instead of assigning the connection to a variable and closing it manually, solve this ?